# POSTGRES (9.6) - Looped Updates to Avoid Running out of Memory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a database table where I want to simply update a column's value for all records that have a certain value in another column.  I can't seem to figure out how to get batch updates working using postgres queries.

The current table structure is like the following:

```
placed_orders (
    order_id uuid,
    source char(1), -- 'A', 'B', or 'C'
    submitted char(1), -- 'Y' or 'N'
    .
    .
    .
)
```

I want to simply update all placed_order rows' source to 'B' where submitted is 'Y', which usually would be as simple as running:

```
UPDATE placed_orders SET source='B' WHERE submitted='Y' AND source!='B';
```

The table is pretty big and has over 5 million records, and if I just ran the above query to update all records at once, I run into out of memory errors, so I'm now looking into the possibility of updating in batches.

The query below is what I have so far,  I'm new to loops and declaring variables and changing its values:

```
DO $test$
DECLARE
    batch_size int := 1000;
    current_offset int := 0;
    records_to_update int := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO records_to_update FROM placed_orders WHERE submitted='Y' AND source !='B';
    FOR j IN 0..records_to_update BY batch_size LOOP
        UPDATE placed_orders SET source = 'B' WHERE order_id IN (SELECT order_id FROM placed_orders WHERE submitted='Y' AND source!='B' ORDER BY order_id ASC OFFSET current_offset LIMIT batch_size);
        current_offset := current_offset + batch_size;
    END LOOP;
END $test$;
```

When running this query, I still get the memory error.  Anyone know how to get it to update in true batches?

Comment: Are you running out of RAM or out of disk-space? What is the error message exactly? Is postgresql running on windows or linux?

Comment: In Postgres an `UPDATE` is a `DELETE/INSERT` operation, which means for each record you have an old(`DELETE`) and new(`INSERT`) row. The problem is that even the `DO` function everything is happening in a single transaction so you are creating a lot of tuples(old and new) before you commit. In later versions of Postgres you can do commits inside the `DO` to mitigate this. You best hope is to do this in a script where you can `UPDATE` in batches, `COMMIT` and then `VACUUM` after each batch.

Comment: It's running on a virtual linux machine.  it says out of shared memory.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @AdrianKlaver!  I figured that might be the case since I did find examples with commits inside the loop but it didn't work with my current version of postgres.

Comment: Just set `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 0 and run the update in a single statement. 5 million rows is not a big table. For detailed analysis (if that doesn't help) please provide the `EXPLAIN` output for your `UPDATE` statement.